# reverse a string using pointers (have to use unsigned *char) in C

Tags: c, string, pointers, unsigned-char

I am currently working on an assignment for Uni.

The task is to reverse a string in a separate function. The function-name is given like that:

> `void string_rev(unsigned char *str);`

My Solution looks like this:

```
void string_rev(unsigned char *str){

    int length = 0;
    int counter = 0;
    unsigned char *endptr = str;   

    for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)  //getting length of string
        length++;

    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)     //putting endptr to end of string
        endptr++;

    while (counter < length/2){      //switch values from start to end until half of string
        char temp = *str;
        *str = *endptr;
        *endptr = temp;
        str++;
        endptr--;
        counter++;
    }


    for (int i = 0; i<length; i++){
        printf("%c", *str);
        str++;
    }

}


int main (void){


    char *array = "Hello";
    unsigned char *ptr = (unsigned char*)array;


    string_rev(ptr);


    return 0;

}
```

The Error I get is Bus Error 10! But I can't find the mistake.

It may has to do with the unsigned char* but I don't get it to work. Can someone please help?

FYI -> We have to use unsigned char*! And of course pointers!

Thank you :)

Comment: Just an aside, you can use `strlen(str)` to get the length of a string. You don't need `for (int i = 0; str[i] != '\0'; i++)
        length++;`. And you can replace `for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)  
        endptr++;` with just `endptr += length;`. Note also that your `endptr` initially points to the trailing null, so your swapping loop will need to take that into account.

Comment: Tip: Change all instances of `unsigned char` to just `char`. After all, you even use `char` inside the function!

Comment: Tip: The second loop can be replaced with `endptr += length;`

Comment: Tip: You don't need `counter`. Simply loop until `endptr < str`.

Comment: Tip: The last loop can be replaced with `printf("%s\n", str);`

Comment: Thank you! Really appreciate your tips! And it works now :D

Comment: I should have said until `endptr <= str`, which is to say while `endptr > str`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You are trying to modify a string constant. Replace

```
char *array = "Hello";   // Not an array.
```

with

```
char array[] = "Hello";
```